# Binding the Contacts and Adding Invite Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, cordova, kendo-mobile

I am making mobile application using Cordova, I am binding the mobile local contacts using the Contacts API from Cordova, now I want to compare local contacts with database or is there any API to do it need help, so I can add invite button.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: i am getting the contact of local phone contacts list by cordova contact API,i want to display  the invite button who are not using my app lik watsapp CONTACTS

Comment: Please provide code you are using for that. provide both server and app side if possible.